# Erro retorno php nusoap

Tags: php, web-service

Ola, eu tenho configurado em um servidor um WebService de licenças,feito em PHP nusoap, que estava funcionando corretamente, porem devido a problemas com a provedora de internet decidimos hospedar em um terceiro, na nova hospedagem ao consumir o WS nao volta o xml de retorno, porem no servidor ele executa o servico notificando no DB a consulta

segue em anexo os codigo do WS e o php info

Edit: eu gravei um txt com a saida do file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), e estava saindo certo

```
<?php
// cliente.php
include('assets/vendor/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$cliente = new nusoap_client('http://ws.orionsistemas.com/licensing/index.php?wsdl');
$parametros = array('CNPJ'=>"12345678901234",'RazaoSocial'=>"razao social","1" ,"1");       
$resultado = $cliente->call('Verifica', $parametros);

echo $resultado;?>


<?php
// servidor.php
include('../assets/vendor/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');


$servidor = new nusoap_server();


$servidor->configureWSDL('urn:ServerOrion');
$servidor->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:ServerOrion';


function Verifica($CNPJ, $RazaoSocial,$Uso_Interno_5,$Uso_Interno_13){
        require_once '../assets/classes/licensing/empresa.class.php';
        require_once '../assets/classes/DB.class.php';
        $empresa = new empresa($CNPJ, $RazaoSocial, $Uso_Interno_5, $Uso_Interno_13);
        $empresa->notifica();
        return $empresa->toXml();
}

$servidor->register(
    'Verifica',
    array(  'CNPJ'=>'xsd:string',
                    'RazaoSocial'=>'xsd:string',
                    'Uso_Interno_5'=>'xsd:string',
                    'Uso_Interno_13'=>'xsd:string'),
    array('retorno'=>'xsd:string'),
    'urn:ServerOrion.Verifica',
    'urn:ServerOrion.Verifica',
            "rpc",
            "encoded",
    'Sistema de licenças Orion Sistemas.'
);
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA_Info = isset(file_get_contents( 'php://input' )) ? file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) : '';
    //$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $servidor->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA_Info);
    //$servidor->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);?>
```

phpinfo();

http://p28-phpinfo.atspace.me/phpinfo.cgi?php=5.6.37

Answer (score 0):

resolvi o problema setando o valor da configuracao

**Always_populate_raw_post_data** para **-1** no *php.ini*